# Replace all occurrences of columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have two columns `Project ID` and `Project Number` in my dataframe `hpds_all_clean` with NAs in them, and I'm trying to replace all NAs occurrences with "Undisclosed Project ID" and "Undisclosed Project Number". Here are some of my attempts which have the same error:

```
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Using `gsub()`:

```
hpds_all_clean %>%
  filter(`Recipient Name-EN` == "Afghanistan") %>%
  hpds_all_clean$`Project Title - EN` = gsub("", "Undisclosed Project ID", hpds_all_clean$`Project Title - EN`) %>%
  hpds_all_clean$`Project Number/Numéro de projet` = gsub("", "Undisclosed Project Number", hpds_all_clean$`Project Number/Numéro de projet`)
```

Using `paste0()`

```
hpds_all_clean %>%
  filter(`Recipient Name-EN` == "Afghanistan") %>%
  paste0(hpds_all_clean, hpds_all_clean$`Project Title - EN`) = "Undisclosed Project ID" %>%
  paste0(hpds_all_clean, hpds_all_clean$`Project Number/Numéro de projet`) = "Undisclosed Project Number"
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these values are NA you can do

```
hpds_all_clean %>% 
  mutate(`Project Title - EN` = if_else(is.na(`Project Title - EN`),"Undisclosed Project ID",`Project Title - EN`),
         `Project Number/Numéro de projet` = if_else(is.na(`Project Number/Numéro de projet`),"Undisclosed Project Number",`Project Number/Numéro de projet`))
```

If these "NA" values are actually "", you would edit within the above to: `` if_else(`Project Title - EN` == "") ``, etc

Answer (score 3):

`replace_na()` in the `tidyr` package can help with this:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  projectID = c('ABC', NA, "DEF", "HIJ", NA),
  projectNumber = c('LMN', "OPQ", "RST", NA, "UVW")
)

df %>% tidyr::replace_na(
  list(
    projectID = "Undisclosed Project ID",
    projectNumber = "Undisclosed Project Number"
  )
)
```

**Output**:

```
               projectID              projectNumber
1                    ABC                        LMN
2 Undisclosed Project ID                        OPQ
3                    DEF                        RST
4                    HIJ Undisclosed Project Number
5 Undisclosed Project ID                        UVW
```